# Join time series dataset with static dataset

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I'm working on reporting dashboards where I need to display different time-series metrics.

My data storage is Google Spreadsheets.

Timeseries data is pretty straightforward: it is the set of responses on daily basis. But I need to join the master dataset (all users) in order to show who has not responded yet.

My datasets:

1. Master dataset (dictionary-like table of all available users);
2. Responses dataset on a daily basis.

As a result, I would like to get a kind of LEFT JOINed dataset where I will have all users on daily basis with related responses or NULL.

Is it possible to resolve with SQL query only?
Or maybe Google Spreadsheets has such functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a key to join on, in the spreadsheet world you should be using either `VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX(MATCH())` to achieve a left join.

Check [this](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/vlookup-function/) resource for more info on how to use these.